# Label centered with input (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to align a label together with an input in the same line and the label centered. If I use the class `label label-default` (wich is the aspect I like), it puts the label aligned on top.

Here’s a sample:

```html
<div class="form-group form-horizontal form-group-sm vertical-align">
    <label for="InputFieldA" class="label control-label label-default col-xs-4">Any</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="InputFieldA" placeholder="InputFieldA">
    </div>
</div>
```

I’ve searched and tested many solutions, but none works (`float:none`, `vertical-align: middle`, embed into a form tag with class form-inline and many more).

I read some 7px margin adding (not tried), but I think it’s incoherent with Bootstrap phiolosophy which all components may resize responsively with device’s size.

I’m not an expert with HTML + Bootstrap 3 + CSS and need some help.

Answer (score 1):

Use absolutely positioned element inside relatively positioned `<label>` element:

```
.col-xs-4 {
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.label-default {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

See demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/4pXvqFcgKx7h8P9rJ0Yc?p=preview

Comment: the height's label for me is correct. Simply I want the label in the middle instead on top.

Comment: I can see it in the middle vertically and horizontally. What browser you use?

Comment: I use Chrome. Your example are aligned, but you changed the label's height.

Comment: So you want something like this? https://plnkr.co/edit/4pXvqFcgKx7h8P9rJ0Yc?p=preview

Comment: I just wrapped the label with a `<div>` and then used `top` and `transform` thick to center the label verticaly.

Comment: Is possible instead of using a fixed 30px height, to make it relative to the input's height or container's height?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.. 
You can use text-center class for getting your text to the center and use the following code for your purpose.
I am using bower to get the components so i have mentioned the links accordingly. Kindly correct me if I have misinterpreted your question.

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style>
    .myLabel{
        display: inline-block;
        height: 34px;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="well-sm"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">
            <label class="myLabel text-center label label-default col-xs-offset-2 col-md-1 col-xs-2">Any
            </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFieldA" placeholder="InputFieldA">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're changing the label's height. If I try your example omitting your line-height, it stays the label on top.

Comment: Alright. aligned it horizontally and vertically in center.

Comment: nop. Your example puts the text algned correctly, but the dark background are resized: ! http://imgur.com/cSxIl1p  i want some like this: ! imgur.com/GXpF2ux

Comment: sorry, nope. It nicer, but keeps modifying the background's label height http://imgur.com/U2d5Wg8

Comment: I finally added all the style from form-control into the label. I guess it would do well this time.

Comment: What a hell! I hoped it is a trivial question and a common need. I'll try the Martin's solution and if I can't achieve my needs, I'll let the browser paint the controls as it considers without loosing more time. I'm tired fighting with an apparently simple frontend need.

Comment: .. and a lot of thanks for your help (and to all of you)

Answer (score 0):

Try This One....

```
 <div class="form-group form-horizontal form-group-sm col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 contr">
   <label for="InputFieldA" class="label control-label label-default col-xs-2"><p class="text-center">Any</p></label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="InputFieldA" placeholder="InputFieldA">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: doesn't work. The <p> tag increases the height but didn't middle-align it: http://imgur.com/bIfhY1Z

Comment: please try this one in <p> tag....                                                                           <p class="text-center" style="padding-top:5px">Any</p>

Comment: I want to mantain the label aspect like this: imgur.com/GXpF2ux